# Large number of char[] instances when profiling program

Tags: java, performance, char, profiling, jprofiler

I have profiled a simple program as below and found a large number of char[] instances to be created. Having read here that char[] instances are usually attributed to Strings, I cant see how this is the case for this program. I know there is a char[] 'name' variable in the Thread class, but surely this should only create 10,000 of these, and so I'm wondering where the additional 35,000 threads have come from?

```
public class untitled {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Thread> a = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            Thread t1 = new Thread();
            a.add(t1);
            t1.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the profiling memory results. There appears to be a umber of String[] instances also.

[image]

Im using this program to isolate some other sections of the profiler. In the full program, the char[] instances increase to ~335,000

Comment: a Thread object is quite heavy and contains many fields, including a `char[]`. You should not create that many threads and use a thread pool instead.

Comment: The actual program I'm running doesnt use this many threads, I was testing something else and discovered this char[] issue. The implementation I'm using is here: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=chameneosredux&lang=java&lang2=java&data=u32

Comment: There's a large number of `char[]` (roughly 2 per String) but not a large volume.

Comment: I guess I should also be asking where these Strings are coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the heap walker in order to answer this question. Select the `char[]` class in the classes view of the heap walker and create a new object set. Then go to the references view and select the "Cumulated incoming references" from the view selector.

[image]

The answer is that roughly a third of the char[] objects belong to strings that are allocated in the JVM by various classes and two thirds come from thread name.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know how you could drill down further to see this information. Exactly what I was looking for. Although, I'm getting different results to this.